# Pass a custom validation rule as a string and get all validation messages

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-8

I'm building a Laravel 8 app that requires user registration. As part of the registration, I need users to provide strong passwords (minimum characters, both lower and upper case letters, numbers and symbols).

Also, for convenience, the rules for the signup request are stored in the database, which means I cannot provide the above rules as object, for example: `['required', Password::min(8)->letters()->mixedCase()->numbers()->symbols()]`, only as a string: `'required,strong_password'`. To do so, I extended Validator with the above rule:

```
Validator::extend('strong_password', Password::min(8)
      ->letters()
      ->mixedCase()
      ->numbers()
      ->symbols());
```

All works well but, when the validation fails, it only provides one error message (`validation.strong_password`, which I can translate).

I want to be able to take advantage of all the messages provided by the Password rule. These are available using the `message()` method of the class, which is never called, because that happens only when the rule is passed as an object that instances Rule (see [vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:562](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L562)):

```
if ($rule instanceof RuleContract) {
  return $validatable
    ? $this->validateUsingCustomRule($attribute, $value, $rule)
    : null;
}

protected function validateUsingCustomRule($attribute, $value, $rule) {
  // some code

    $messages = $rule->message();

  // mode code
}
```

The question is: how can I register the custom rule and store it in database as a string in order to benefit from its `message()` method that is only called when the rule is passed as object?

Answer (score -1):

I would recomend using costome validation as per laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation)

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'password' => 'required|min:8',

    ];
}
```

I hope it works well for you

Comment: The rules are stored in a database. Furthermore, I want mixed case, numbers and symbols AND all failure messages that Password provides.

Comment: you complicate life while there are simple ways to do it. First you shouldn't store messages in database while you can write them in string, because you make your application slow and heavy. If you must do it. you must fetch data from your validation model and call as variable which is time consuming and waste your time than simply passing string

Comment: I'm not storing messages in a database. I'm storing rules in a database, this allows the client to edit forms and validations.